# Facing problem when try to create pie chart with 11g forms

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, pie-chart, oracleforms

I want to show pie chart with 11g form. For this reason I wrote this code. The chart is showing but with this code only first row is populating the chart. That means if query retrieve two rows like-

```
gen    emp
---    ----
male   5
female 3
```

then the chart showed 100% based on 1st row(male 5) data.

Here is my code :

```
declare
  cursor graph1 is
  SELECT GENDER GEN,COUNT(*) EMP
    FROM EMP_INFO
   GROUP BY GENDER
   ORDER BY 2 DESC;

  vd varchar2(1):=',';
begin
    go_block('control1');
    clear_record;
    first_record;
  for j in graph1 loop
        SET_CUSTOM_PROPERTY('control1.b_g',1,'ADD_ROWDATA','Gender'||VD||J.EMP||VD||j.GEN);
        SET_CUSTOM_PROPERTY('control1.b_g',1,'ADD_DATA_TO_GRAPH','AREA_VERT_ABS');
        SET_CUSTOM_PROPERTY('control1.b_g',1,'GRAPHTYPE','PIE_GRAPH');
        SET_CUSTOM_PROPERTY('control1.b_g',1,'MOUSEACTION','FALSE');
        SET_CUSTOM_PROPERTY('control1.b_g',1,'SET_BACKGROUND','0,255,255');
        SET_CUSTOM_PROPERTY('control.b_g',1,'SHOW_GRAPH','');
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: try to replace the second argument for `SET_CUSTOM_PROPERTY` method to a iteration yielding `1,2..` instead of fixed value `1`.

Comment: I tried this way -> **`SET_CUSTOM_PROPERTY('control1.b_g',1,2,'ADD_ROWDATA','EMP'||VD||J.EMP||VD||j.GEN);`**      it didn't work. I will be pleased if you provide me any example or link Mr. @BarbarosÖzhan